# How to work with negative correlation in a bivariate normal distribution

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, bivariate

What is the standard deviation of their combined income if their incomes have a bivariate normal distribution and the correlation between them is 0.4? What is it if the correlation is -0.4?

I calculated the standard deviation of the combined income using this formula for 0.4. What do I do with the negative correlation?

σ_W = √(σ_X^2 〖+σ〗_Y^2+2pσ_X σ_Y )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For correlation = -0.4, evaluate the formula using p = -0.4.  Just as you presumably evaluated it using p = 0.4 for correlation = 0.4.